# Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myapp-ws.war\" Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective

Tags: java, maven, web-services, jboss, wildfly-18

Presently, I have an `ejb` project and a web service project.  The problem is that my webservice project cannot access EJBs from my library project:

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myapp-ws.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myapp-ws.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class org.ws.MyAppWSImpl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.myapp-ws.war\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/myapp/MyAppStatelessLocal;
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.myappp.InfossStatelessLocal from [Module \"deployment.myapp-ws.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
```

As far as I can tell the dependencies are setup properly in the `pom.xml` files.  Here is my root pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <modules>
        <module>myapp-ejb</module>
        <module>myapp-web</module>      
        <module>myapp-ear</module>
        <module>myapp-ws</module>       
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <root.dir>${project.basedir}</root.dir>
        <jboss.home.name>JBOSS_HOME</jboss.home.name>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <version.server.bom>18.0.1.Final</version.server.bom>
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>2.0.0.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
        <version.jaxws-tools-maven-plugin>1.2.3.Final</version.jaxws-tools-maven-plugin>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.server.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>               
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-ejb</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>ejb</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-web</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>           
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-ws</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>                   
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    ...
</project>
```

Here my my `ear` pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <name>myapp-ear</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <description>This project packages myapp-ejb and myapp-web in an EAR; this is the EAR POM file</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp-ejb</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp-web</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp-ws</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
   ...
</project>
```

Here is my web service `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-ws</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <name>myapp-ws Maven Soap WS</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp-ejb</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    ....
</project>
```

The `ear` project deploys without a problem but the webservice deployment fails.  Basically, I am trying to follow this guide:

https://docs.wildfly.org/18/Getting_Started_Developing_Applications_Guide.html

https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/10.x/guide/HelloworldQuickstart.asciidoc

https://developers.redhat.com/quickstarts/eap/helloworld-ws#

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA

**UPDATE:**

Here is my `MyAppWSImpl.java`:

```
package myapp.ws;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import myapp.lab.MyAppStatelessLocal;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "myapp.ws.MyAppWS")
public class MyAppWSImpl implements MyAppWS {
    @EJB
    MyAppStatelessLocal masl;
            
    @WebMethod()
    public String predict(int value) {
        return masl.getPrediction(value);
    }
}
```

Here is my `web.xml`.  HTH.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>myapp-ws</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myappws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myapp.ws.MyAppWSImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myappws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myappws</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that I finally figured out that I needed to use this URL:

http://localhost:8080/myapp-ws/myappws?wsdl

Instead of this value:

http://localhost:8080/myapp-ws/MyAppWSImpl?wsdl